# Creating custom search button in Notepad++

Tags: search, button, notepad++

I am looking for a way to create custom buttons for Notepad++. So far I haven't been able to find solutions regarding this.

The buttons would be doing a regular expression search and highlight the search results as well. This would make it much easier for me to analyze error logs. This would eliminate the need of copy/pasting the long regex search queries.

I'm trying to use the Customize Toolbar plugin to accomplish this, but I couldn't find a thorough documentation of it and therefore having troubles.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There you go:

1. Download "Customize Toolbar" from the "Plugin Manager"
2. Go to menu "Plugins" > "Customize Toolbar"  and select "Custom Buttons"
3. Restart Notepad++
4. Now it's the important part, where you need to create the button's functionality. In your case you want to simply search and fortunately this can be implemented in a Macro. If you need something more complex that can't be recorded in a Macro, consider the use of "Python Script" plugin (which is really easy even with a minimal knowledge of Python) or writing your own plugin (which I guess is more difficult, I never tried to). So, let us assume that you recorded a Macro and you named it "test".
5. Find and open the file `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\plugins\config\CustomizeToolbar.btn`
6. Add the following new row in the file:

   > Macro,test,,,

That's all. You now have a new button in your toolbar that runs your macro.

Comment: Hi, I came across as I've similar problem but I don't seem to be able to find the `CustomizeToolbar.btn` file instead there is a binary file with the same name but `.dat` extension. On the same lines, if my macro is named `Run those lines in ` shall I add the name in inverted commas?

Comment: @Konrad, I am sorry that I cannot help, since I am not using this software anymore. But I remember that there was a .btn and a .dat file with the same name, on this folder. So, I would suggest to check if you do have the latest Notepad++ and reinstall the Customize Toolbar plugin.

Comment: @Konrad if you are still wondering where the original file "CustomizeToolbar.btn" appears, it shows when you click "Plugins > Customize Toolbar > Custom Buttons".

Comment: update: pythonscript was awesome but it only support python 2.7.6 (and won't be updated).

Comment: After update of NPP I had a little problem (using German UI):
the menu was no longer called "Makro"  but  "Makros". This need to be fixed in customizeToolbar.btn - then everything fine again