# How to add custom buttons to Notepad ++ (64-bit)?

Tags: button, notepad++

Like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630562/creating-custom-search-button-in-notepad), I have a desire to add custom buttons in Notepad ++ to speed up my workflow. It suggests that we first need to install a 'Pluggins Manager' that has since been removed, but available for download for 32-bit version of the application, but alas I am using the 64-bit version.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301700/how-to-view-plugin-manager-in-notepad) another user asks how to view the Pluggin Manger in the 64-bit version of Notepad ++, and the top answer (which I think is from one of the devs), states that the Pluggin Manger is no longer shipped with Notepad ++.
Another user mentions that is now included as of version V8 (I am running V8.1.9.2), but it doesn't seem to be present, or I don't know what I am looking for.

So, this leaves me with a bunch of outdated info with not much to work on.

Can anyone tell me the current way to add custom buttons to Notepad ++ (64-bit)?

Comment: "Plugins manager" has been replaced with new functionality, use menu => *Plugins* => *Plugins admin*.  For the buttons, try the documentation at https://npp-user-manual.org .

Comment: I have added the 'Customize Toolbar' in => Plugins => Plugins admin, but don't see any new buttons after activating this.

Comment: There's more to do with the plugin. After the plugin is added, go to `Plugins` => `Customize Toolbar` and then (if not already done) click the `Custom Buttons` option so that it is checked. Then restart Notepad++. After restart, navigate to: `%AppData%\Notepad++\plugins\config`, to find the `CustomizeToolbar.btn` file where the button customization's are added. Within this file, I un-commented the line for `Edit,Select All,,,*R:SA,*R:SA`, saved and restarted notepad++. After restart, a red button with SA appeared at the far right end of the toolbar, so this plugin works in my v8.1.9.3

Comment: @PaulT. You are the real MVP! I was fruitlessly searching for the freaking .btn file in the ProgramFiles\...\plugins folder, instead of %AppData%! Plugin Admin misleadingly leads to ProgramFiles when you press "open plugins foder" =(